# Find the support of a module and associated primes

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules

> I have the module $M=k[x,y]/(x+y)$ and I must find the sets Supp(M) and Ass(M).

Could anyone give me a tip how to make it. I have no idea about how to make it. Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

**Hint.** $k[X,Y]/(X+Y)$ is an integral domain isomorphic to ...

Comment: Thank youYACP.. But If k[x,y]/(x+y) is an integral domain its means that the ideal (x+y) is prime so AssM={(x+y)}.is that correct YACP??

Comment: could you give me any advice about SuppM??again thanks..